# XAMPP: Apache shutdown unexpectedly occurred when UPDATED my XAMPP Version

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I tried to install new version of xampp. The folder that containing the xampp. I named it as *xampp1* then i deleted the older version/folder of xampp. After that i changed the *xampp1* folder to *xampp* when i finally installed the newest version of xampp and started the apache and mysql this error occurred and says:

```
10:22:13 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:22:13 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 

10:22:13 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

10:22:13 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:22:13 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:22:13 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:22:13 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

I've been searching for the solution of this like reading some blogs and stackover flow thread. I tried also to change some line of codes in **httpd.conf** and **httpd-ssl.conf** from *80* to *8080* and *443* to *4433* and restart the xampp and start it again. But it doesn't work for me. Help me out please. I was afraid to do the youtube tutorials on how to update xampp. But i needed to update my xampp and i think there's something wrong with my actions when i updated my xampp.

Comment: are you using skype?

Comment: I don't use skype sir and i uninstalled it. Some of the thread are trying to change the port of skype but i dont have skype in my laptop